# Submit on select (Yii)

Tags: php, yii

Trying to make a dropdown list, which should be submitted if any option is selected.
I followed the instructions from this [article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/11/how-to-filter-data-using-a-dropdown-list), but no success — the page is not reloading, nothing happens at all.
Here's my code:

```
<?php echo CHtml::form('','get', array('class'=>'catalog-select')); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('the_cats','select_value',array(1=>'bla',2=>'blabla'),array('submit'=>'')
    );?>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

 <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('the_cats','select_value',array(1=>'bla',2=>'blabla'),array('submit'=>'','class'=>'catalog-select')
    );?>


<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Comment: But, how can I add css class to the form?
When i'm adding it, the form stops working.

Comment: I've needed to add class to a form, not to a dropdownlist.
But forget about it, I've already implemented it with js.